# Issue with a multiple regression model in R

Tags: r, statistics, regression, stat

First let me apologize but I'm a biologist starting in the world of bioinformatics and therefore in R programming and statistics. 
I have to do an analysis of a multilinear regression model with the data (Penta) from Library(mvdalav).

I have to try different models including the PLS model that is the model that is normally used for this data set (https://rdrr.io/cran/mvdalab/f/README.md)

However, they ask us to play with the data more models and I'm very lost as the data seems to always give me errors:

1) Normal multiple regression model:

```
> mod2<-mod1<-lm(Penta1$log.RAI~.,Penta1)
> summary(mod2)

Call:
lm(formula = Penta1$log.RAI ~ ., data = Penta1)

Residuals:
ALL 30 residuals are 0: no residual degrees of freedom!

Coefficients: (15 not defined because of singularities)
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   -1.000e-01         NA      NA       NA
Obs.NameAAWAA  8.500e-01         NA      NA       NA
Obs.NameAAYAA  5.600e-01         NA      NA       NA
Obs.NameEKWAP  1.400e+00         NA      NA       NA
Obs.NameFEAAK  4.000e-01         NA      NA       NA
Obs.NameFSPFR  7.400e-01         NA      NA       NA
Obs.NameGEAAK -4.200e-01         NA      NA       NA
Obs.NameLEAAK  5.000e-01         NA      NA       NA
Obs.NamePGFSP  1.000e+00         NA      NA       NA
Obs.NameRKWAP  2.080e+00         NA      NA       NA
Obs.NameRYLPT  5.000e-01         NA      NA       NA
Obs.NameVAAAK  1.114e-15         NA      NA       NA
Obs.NameVAAWK  3.300e-01         NA      NA       NA
Obs.NameVAWAA  1.530e+00         NA      NA       NA
Obs.NameVAWAK  1.550e+00         NA      NA       NA
Obs.NameVEAAK  6.100e-01         NA      NA       NA
Obs.NameVEAAP  2.800e-01         NA      NA       NA
Obs.NameVEASK  3.000e-01         NA      NA       NA
Obs.NameVEFAK  1.670e+00         NA      NA       NA
Obs.NameVEGGK -9.000e-01         NA      NA       NA
Obs.NameVEHAK  1.630e+00         NA      NA       NA
Obs.NameVELAK  6.900e-01         NA      NA       NA
Obs.NameVESAK  3.800e-01         NA      NA       NA
Obs.NameVESSK  1.000e-01         NA      NA       NA
Obs.NameVEWAK  2.830e+00         NA      NA       NA
Obs.NameVEWVK  1.810e+00         NA      NA       NA
Obs.NameVKAAK  2.100e-01         NA      NA       NA
Obs.NameVKWAA  1.810e+00         NA      NA       NA
Obs.NameVKWAP  2.450e+00         NA      NA       NA
Obs.NameVWAAK  1.400e-01         NA      NA       NA
S1                    NA         NA      NA       NA
L1                    NA         NA      NA       NA
P1                    NA         NA      NA       NA
S2                    NA         NA      NA       NA
L2                    NA         NA      NA       NA
P2                    NA         NA      NA       NA
S3                    NA         NA      NA       NA
L3                    NA         NA      NA       NA
P3                    NA         NA      NA       NA
S4                    NA         NA      NA       NA
L4                    NA         NA      NA       NA
P4                    NA         NA      NA       NA
S5                    NA         NA      NA       NA
L5                    NA         NA      NA       NA
P5                    NA         NA      NA       NA

Residual standard error: NaN on 0 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:      1, Adjusted R-squared:    NaN 
F-statistic:   NaN on 29 and 0 DF,  p-value: NA
```

2) Study the reduced model provided by the stepwise method. The aim is to compare the RMSE of the reduced model and the complete model for the training group and for the test group.

`step(lm(log.RAI~.,data = penta),direction = "backward")
Error in step(lm(log.RAI ~ ., data = penta), direction = "backward") : 
  AIC is -infinity for this model, so 'step' cannot proceed`

3)Find the best model by the criteria of the AIC and by the adjusted R2

4) PLS model --> what fits the data following:https://rdrr.io/cran/mvdalab/f/README.md

5)Also study it  with the Ridge Regression method with the `lm.ridge ()` function or similar
6) Finally we will study the LASSO method with the `lars ()` function of Lasso project.

I'm super lost with why the data.frame gave those errors and also how to develop the analysis. Any help with any of the parts would be much appreciated

Kind regards

Comment: you have that error because most of your observations are n=1. I noticed you have Penta1. How is it different from Penta in the library(mvdalav)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after reading the vignette, Penta is some data obtained from drug discovery and the first column is the unique identifier. To do regression or downstream analysis you need to exclude this column. For the steps below, I simply do Penta[,-1] as input data

For the first part, this works:

```
library(mvdalab)
data(Penta)
summary(lm(log.RAI~.,data = Penta[,-1]))

Call:
lm(formula = log.RAI ~ ., data = Penta[, -1])

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.39269 -0.12958 -0.05101  0.07261  0.63414 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept) -0.80263    0.92495  -0.868  0.40016   
S1          -0.09783    0.03895  -2.512  0.02489 * 
L1           0.03236    0.04973   0.651  0.52576   
P1          -0.10795    0.08521  -1.267  0.22587   
S2           0.08670    0.04428   1.958  0.07043 .
```

Second part for AIC is ok as well:

```
 step(lm(log.RAI~.,data = Penta[,-1]),direction="backward")
Start:  AIC=-57.16
log.RAI ~ S1 + L1 + P1 + S2 + L2 + P2 + S3 + L3 + P3 + S4 + L4 + 
    P4 + S5 + L5 + P5

       Df Sum of Sq    RSS     AIC
- P3    1   0.00150 1.5374 -59.132
- L4    1   0.00420 1.5401 -59.080
```

If you want to select model with AIC, the one above works. For adjusted R^2 i think most likely there are packages out there that does this

For lm.ridge, do the same:

```
library(MASS)
fit=lm.ridge(log.RAI~.,data = Penta[,-1])
```

For lars, lasso, you need to have the predictors etc in a matrix, so let's do

```
library(lars)
data = as.matrix(Penta[,-1])
fit = lars(x=data[,-ncol(data)],y=data[,"log.RAI"],type="lasso")
```

Comment: As you are new to SO, just to let you know, if the answer solved your question you can consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark (please don't though). https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this (definitely no obligation in this case).

Comment: Done!  Just one question, what do you mean with "If you want to select model with AIC, the one above works". The code `step(lm(log.RAI~.,data = Penta[,-1]),direction="backward")` is for the stpewise model, right??

Comment: yes that's correct. If you do step, it selects by AIC. for example, selectAIC = step(lm(log.RAI~.,data = Penta[,-1]),direction="backward")

Comment: One more question in case you  know... I need to separate my data into a training set and a test set `set.seed(321)
idx <- sample(1:30, size = 20, replace = F)
ptrain <- Penta[idx,]
ptest <- Penta[-idx,]` But then the code does never work for the test data, but does nicely for the ptrain data: `> step(lm(log.RAI~.,data = ptest[,-1]),direction="backward")
Error in step(lm(log.RAI ~ ., data = ptest[, -1]), direction = "backward") : 
  AIC is -infinity for this model, so 'step' cannot proceed' and `step(lm(log.RAI~.,data = ptest[,-1]),direction="backward")` works perfectly. Any thoughts??

Comment: If I run your code, I don't get an error. You should check again. One last thing might be to restart your r session, so you don't have anything weird environment variables in it